# Grails find / findAll operation won't work?

Tags: grails, groovy, active-directory, ldap, findall

I'm trying to build a Grails application which can do LDAP lookups. I've been following a few guides ([link text](http://www.grails.org/LDAP+Plugin) and some others) but to no end I'm afraid.

Relevant source code:
From config.groovy:

```
ldap {
directories    { 
    dir1 {
        url = "ldap://dc01"
        base = "ou=someou,dc=check,dc=nl"
        userDn = "cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=check,dc=nl"
        password = "wowthisisnothepassword"
    }
}

schemas = [
    ldapclient.GldapoSchemaClassForUser
]}
```

My domainclass:

```
package ldapclient
import gldapo.schema.annotation.GldapoNamingAttribute
import gldapo.schema.annotation.GldapoSynonymFor
import gldapo.schema.annotation.GldapoSchemaFilter

@GldapoSchemaFilter("(objectclass=person)")
class GldapoSchemaClassForUser {
   @GldapoNamingAttribute
   String uid

   @GldapoSynonymFor("cn")
   String name

   @GldapoSynonymFor("mail")
   String email

   @GldapoSynonymFor("uid")
   String username

   @GldapoSynonymFor("fullname")
   String fullName
}
```

And my controller:

```
package ldapclient

class AdController {
def defaultAction = "list"

List matches = GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAll(
    filter: "(name=s*)"
)

def list = {
    [ "adMatches" : matches.list() ]
}}
```

Although my program conforms (for as far as I can tell) to what should work according to the many documents, I cannot run this. The error thrown:

*Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static ldapclient.GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[filter:(name=s*)]]
    at ldapclient.AdController.(AdController.groovy:6)*

Any clues what's going on / wrong? I'm on Grails 1.2.3 and using the most current version of the LDAP plugin. The project is clean (freshly created).

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for the response; I just upgraded to Grails 1.3.4 and moved some files around. This did some good, though I still get this nasty error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'ldapclient.AdController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [ldapclient.AdController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static ldapclient.GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[directory:dir1, filter:(uid=myname,ou=st,ou=ouou,dc=dc,dc=dcdc)]] Possible solutions: findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Answer (score 3):

Where are your schema classes located? I have this plugin working fine (albeit with Grails 1.3.4). Note that your link to the plugin is an old-ish page. Here is the latest I believe: [Grails LDAP Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ldap).

Don't think there's much difference other than it looks like you can drop schema classes in the *grails-app/ldap* directory instead of having to specify them in Config - I do it the same way as you with schemas specified in the config, but might be worth trying them in the grails-app/ldap folder?

Answer (score 2):

[According to documentation](http://www.grails.org/DomainClass+Dynamic+Methods#findAll), findAll method has only this definitions (where Book - is sample domain class):

```
Book.findAll()
Book.findAll( String query )
Book.findAll( String query, Collection positionalParams )
Book.findAll( String query, Collection positionalParams, Map paginateParams )
Book.findAll( String query, Map namedParams )
Book.findAll( String query, Map namedParams, Map paginateParams )
Book.findAll( Book example )
```

And your code:

```
List matches = GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAll(
    filter: "(name=s*)"
)
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
List matches = GldapoSchemaClassForUser.findAllByNameLike("s%")
```

Or use [criteria definition](http://www.grails.org/DomainClass+Dynamic+Methods#createCriteria):

```
List matches = GldapoSchemaClassForUser.list() {
     like("name","s%")
}
```

To use filters - look at [Hibernate-filter plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter)

Comment: The Gldapp schema classes are not grails/hibernate domain classes so they don't have the same conventions. There is a DSL for the find and findAll (http://gldapo.codehaus.org/schemaclasses/searching.html), so the findAll(filter: "...") *should* be valid.

Comment: What @Chris said… although the link in this comment is no longer working.  The [Grails LDAP Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ldap) page also seems out of date. You might have to look into the source (either https://github.com/codehaus/gldapo or https://github.com/alkemist/Gldapo, I suspect).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a couple of days using grails 2.2 with ldap plugin 0.8.2. After digging through the gldapo mailing list archive, I found out that this occurs because the schema class is not injected with Gldapo behavior and hence the find/findAll() methods are not resolved correctly. Refer to this thread - http://markmail.org/message/v5ulptrxzfoq4ml7

I had missed using 'import myPkg.SchemaClass' in my grails Config.groovy script.