# Trying to get the Grails ldap-0.8.2 plugin to work for non-authentication searching of AD

Tags: ldap

I've been trying to get the ldap-0.8.2 or gldapo plugin to work with Grails 2.3.5 to perform a simple person search in AD. I'm not looking for authentication, just to build a person directory search form. I have close to a week now looking at old references to problems implementing this plugin and just can not seem to figure out what the right combination of fiery hoops to jump through are.

In BuildConfig.groovy I have:

```
compile ":ldap:0.8.2"
```

In Config.groovy I have:

```
import edu.fgcu.gtd.GldapoUser

ldap {
   directories {
       directory1 {
           defaultDirectory = true
           url = "ldap://FGCU-AMBERJACK.primary.ad.fgcu.edu"
           userDn = "CN=******,OU=******,OU=******,OU=******,DC=**,DC=**,DC=***,DC=***"
           password = "********"
           searchControls {
               countLimit = 40
               timeLimit = 600
               searchScope = "subtree"
           }
       }
   }
   schemas: [edu.fgcu.gtd.GldapoUser]
}
```

I have the following groovy file at path "Ldap/edu/fgcu/gtd/GldapoUser.groovy"

```
package edu.fgcu.gtd

import gldapo.schema.annotation.GldapoNamingAttribute
import gldapo.schema.annotation.GldapoSynonymFor
import gldapo.schema.annotation.GldapoSchemaFilter
/**
 *
 * @author pallen
 */
@GldapoSchemaFilter("(objectclass=person)")
class GldapoUser {

    @GldapoSynonymFor("uid")
    String username

    @GldapoSynonymFor("cn")
    String name

    @GldapoSynonymFor("title")
    String title

    @GldapoSynonymFor("physicalDeliveryOfficeName")
    String office

    @GldapoSynonymFor("telephoneNumber")
    String phone

    @GldapoSynonymFor("mail")
    String email

    @GldapoSynonymFor("department")
    String department
}
```

And then I have the following controller

```
package edu.fgcu.gtd

import edu.fgcu.gtd.GldapoUser

class PersonSearchController {

    def index() {
        render(view: "search")
    }

    def search() {
        String searchString = params?.lastName + "*"
        if (params.firstName){
            searchString += "," + params.firstName + "*"
        }
        def List personSearchList = GldapoUser.findAll(
             base: "OU=Florida Gulf Coast University,DC=primary,DC=ad,DC=fgcu,DC=edu") {
                    like "cn", searchString
             }
        respond personSearchList, model:[personSearchCount: personSearchList.count()]
    }
}
```

When I run the application I receive the following error, which I have seen others reference, but none of the suggestions that I have found so far have helped me resolve this.

```
    URI: /GroovyGTD/personSearch/search
  Class: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message: No signature of method: static edu.fgcu.gtd.GldapoUser.findAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, edu.fgcu.gtd.PersonSearchController$_search_closure1) values: [[base:OU=Florida Gulf Coast University,DC=primary,DC=ad,DC=fgcu,DC=edu], ...] Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I'm relatively new to Grails, but am fairly adept with Java, and have worked through some difficult configurations for external libraries, but this plugin has me stumped.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Just want to add that I went through this older post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834959/grails-find-findall-operation-wont-work) but was still not successful.

Comment: I've gone back painstakingly through the link from the previous post carefully, and have picked up on a few things. I noticed that I had an error in Config.groovy where I had schemas:[] should have been schemas = [].  This has gotten me further and I'm now looking at the annotations in my GldapoUser class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it all to work.

First issue was the schemas comment.  I had to put schemas = [ edu.fgcu.gtd.GldapoUser] in config.groovy.

Next I had to add a @GldapoNamingAttribute to my GldapoUser object for the "cn" attribute, and "uid" is not in my AD person entry so I got rid of it and used the "sAMAccountName" for username.

It is all working well after those few changes.